# revert to null after strcat

Tags: c, strcat

I am trying to strcat a pathname to pass to fopen to create multiple filenames in a while loop.

```
char path[30]="";
while(!feof(stdin))
{
    strncat(path,folder,8);
    strcat(path,filename);
    strncat(path,ext,4);
    printf("file path:%s\n",path);
    File[n] = fopen(path,"a");
    path=0;
}
```

How do I return path to an empty char array so i can concatenate again?
Or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: segmentation faults because path keeps the old string after it loops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it is null terminated, just do

```
path[0] = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [memset()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/memset/) function. It will allow to you to clean a array.

Write:

```
memset((void*)path, 0, 30*sizeof(char));
```

instead of

```
path = 0;
```

Comment: Why he must set 0 to all elements of `path` ?

Answer (score 0):

Change `path=0;` to `path[0] = 0;`. This will make the string empty.

Answer (score 0):

set path[0] = 0; Such routine take notice of 0 as an end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `snprintf` to create the content of the path

```
#define MAX_PATH_SIZE 30
char path[MAX_PATH_SIZE] = "";
while (!feof(stdin))
{
  snprintf(path, MAX_PATH_SIZE, "%s%s%s", folder, filename, ext);
  printf("file path:%s\n",path);
  File[n] = fopen(path,"a");
}
```